# Can I draw any more conclusions about this number?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I have a number $m$ which is a perfect square (this isn't really relevant, at least not that I'm aware of). I also have a function $f: \mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathbb {N}$ such that $f(m)$ is also a perfect square.

I know that $f(m) - 9k$ is a perfect square for some $k$ in $\mathbb {N_0}$. The only conclusion I could draw from this is that $9|f(m)$. Can I say anything else about f(m)?

Edit: Forgot to mention that 9 does not necessarily divide f(m) if k=0

Comment: What if $f(m)=4$ or $16$?

Comment: Then the only k such that f(m) - 9k is a perfect square is k = 0

Comment: If $f(m)=25$ then $k$ might be $1$ but $9$ does not divide $f(m)$.

Comment: Hmmm you're right